# Hypothesis Testing Biased vs Unbiased Coin with One Flip

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution, binomial-distribution, hypothesis-testing

You're given a coin to flip and you only can flip it once. The null hypothesis is that it is unbiased. The alternate hypothesis is that it is twice as likely to land heads than it is tails. Create a powerful test with 90% confidence and calculate the power.

If you can help me with that question, it would be much appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Use the Neyman-Person Lemma. Note for $x\in\{0,1\}$ $$\frac{L_X(\frac{1}{2},x)}{L_X(\frac{2}{3},x)}=\frac{P(X=x|p=1/2)}{P(X=x|p=2/3)}$$ where $X\sim \text{Bernoilli}(p).$

Comment: How could I use that to make a test with 90% significance and a high power in this scenario if the coin is only being flipped once?

Comment: What would your decision be if you flipped the coin and it came up heads?

Comment: Since I want 90% confidence, could I reject the null hypothesis if it came up heads multiplied by a probability c where 1/2 * c = .10? So c would be .20, meaning that if heads comes up, then 20% of the time I will reject the null hypothesis and 80% of the time I will be unable to reject the null. If tails, then reject the null. This gives me a 90% significance because the max possibility of a Type 1 error is 10% in this case (since I'll never reject the null more than 10% of the time)? Is this logical thinking or am I off? I'm still not sure how to connect it to the Neyman-Person Lemma.

Comment: Do you want $90$% confidence or $90$% significance? Your post says that you want $90$% significance i.e. $\alpha =90$%. Also, you can't just multiply a probability by a constant of your own liking. The probability is entirely determined by the outcome of the coin flip and the decision you make depending on its outcome. Now if your significance is actually $10$%, the only way you're going to get the probability of a Type I error ($\alpha$) to be less than $10$% is if you never reject $H_0$.

Comment: Sorry I meant significance level is α=.10. Would that mean that the only way to achieve that is to never reject H0? But then the test would have zero power right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/119437/discussion-between-matthew-pilling-and-stats14421).